# Join multiple tables using IF ELSE statement

Tags: mysql

I want to Join multiple tables using `IF ELSE` statement within Sql Query when column value match with the specified text.

Suppose I have checked `coloumnName='Value'` Then I want to JOIN an additional Table; otherwise, I do not want to join it. Is this possible? How can I do that?

Comment: And what fields should be in the result set for the rows with and without joined table, may I ask?

Comment: You have a very poorly formed "question".  First, there is no question.  Second, you should say what your inputs are and desired output.  Preferably, you should also have an attempt that you have made to solve the problem.

Comment: You could only do this through your application not SQL itself.  You would need to write your own query builder logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot conditionally join a table You need to join all tables unconditionally using an outer join, use the condition in the join criteria, and pick the values that you want from the returned data set, like this:

```
select r.id, p.name, a.name, t.name
from requests r
left outer join person p on r.type='person' and r.item_id = p.id
left outer join animal a on r.type='animal' and r.item_id = a.id
left outer join thing t on r.type='thing' and r.item_id = t.id
```

The example above shows "requests" that have an `item_id` that references a person, an animal, or a thing. The `type` column decides which table is referenced.

The result will have three columns for `name`, at most one of which will be non-null.